# Can't add 2 levels Foreign key fields to pydantic model creator Tortoise ORM

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic, tortoise-orm

I have this 3 models (using Tortoise ORM and FastApi)

```
class Faena(Model):

id = fields.UUIDField(pk=True)
nombre = fields.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)

# Foreign Keys
empresa = fields.ForeignKeyField('models.Empresa', related_name='faenas_empresa', null=True)


class Instalacion(Model):

id = fields.UUIDField(pk=True)
descripcion = fields.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)

#Foreign Keys
faena = fields.ForeignKeyField('models.Faena', related_name='instalaciones_faena', null=True)


class Empresa(Model):

id = fields.UUIDField(pk=True)
rut = fields.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)
```

**And here are my pydantic schemas:**

```
Tortoise.init_models(["app.api.v1.models"], "models")

 get_deposito = pydantic_model_creator(Instalacion,name="get_deposito",include=('id','faena.empresa.rut','faena.nombre',))
```

When I print **get_deposito.schema_json(indent=2)** There is no field **'faena.empresa.rut'**, I can only see id and faena.nombre fields....What am I doing wrong ??

Thanks for your help

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I suggest you read the articles on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), then use the _Edit_ function to modify your question accordingly.
The practice of boiling the code down to the bare minimum needed to capture the essence of the problem not only motivates others to actually try and help you but more often than not gives you a deeper understanding to solve the problem yourself.